# How to view the raw XML or Json response using LinqToTwitter?

Tags: linq, twitter, linq-to-twitter

How can I view the raw XML or Json response when doing a search for users using the LinqToTwitter library? I'm using the SingleUserAuthorizer for oAuth.

If you have any ideas using other libraries or even a simple oAuth framework, I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TwitterContext has a RawResults property you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for debugging purposes, I'd use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - that way you get to see the complete HTTP requests/responses.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. I'm already using Fiddler to view the raw response. But I need the results inside my ASP.NET application.

Comment: @draconis: So why do you need the *raw* results rather than just what the API gives you? It sounds like a bit of an encapsulation violation - other than for debugging, you shouldn't usually care about the bits under the hood, just the results.

Comment: My client asked me to use Juitter, which is a client-side jQuery app, to display the Twitter query results. But he asked me to retrieve the results server-side for security reasons (use of oAuth). So - I have a page that queries Twitter, then outputs the raw results. Juitter does a json call on my page, retrieves the results and displays them.

Comment: @draconis: It sounds like the best bet would be to modify LINQ to Twitter in this case. It's open source, so it may well be pretty straightforward... check the licence, of course.

Comment: I've already got this working for the tweet search page. That's fine because I do the request and response handling manually, so the raw http response is accessible. But for user search, oAuth is required, and I don't have the know-how to code it myself at a webrequest/webresponse level.